# After Delete Command executes view is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I am using **relay command** to ***delete*** some data's from list-item, 
I have list of sites, for which I am using **observable collection** to get automatic notifications.

```
public SiteMainUC_VM()
    {
        deleteSiteCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DeleteSite);
        selectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(this.FilterSite);

        List<SiteDetails> parameters = MasterLink.Model.DALService.ConfigEngine.GetAllSites();
        listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(parameters);

    }
    private ICommand deleteSiteCommand;
    public ICommand DeleteSiteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return deleteSiteCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            value = deleteSiteCommand;
        }
    }


    public void DeleteSite()
    {

        var Result = MessageBox.Show("Do You Need to Delete Site Details", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
               MasterLink.Model.DALService.ConfigEngine.RemoveSite(Selectedsites);
                List<SiteDetails> parameters = MasterLink.Model.DALService.ConfigEngine.GetAllSites();
                listofsites = new ObservableCollection<SiteDetails>(parameters);
                //CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Listofsites).Refresh();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Site Not Found !");
            }

        }


    }
```

Now inside **xaml** , I have **list-box** from where I am using **image as delete button**, after clicking delete function working fine but ui not updating,
binding code is below

```
<Button Canvas.Right="0" Canvas.Top="5" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteSiteCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" IsEnabled="True"  BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                                    <!--<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DeleteSiteCommand}"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>-->
                                    <Grid>

                                        <Image Source="/MasterLink;component/Resources/i_delete_UM.png" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                                    </Grid>

                                </Button>
```

Comment: Where are you deleting the item from the `ObservableCollection`? I only see you removing item from the underlying `ConfigEngine`.

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `listofsites` property.

Comment: @mike that is already done, though not included that portion here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the **canExecute** predicate while creating a new relay command for it to work. You could set it to true so that it will work when ever the button is clicked. Try the code below. It should work.

```
deleteSiteCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DeleteSite, param => true);
selectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(this.FilterSite, param => true);
```

Also you need to raise the property changed event with command for binding to work properly.

```
private ICommand deleteSiteCommand;
public ICommand DeleteSiteCommand
{
    get
    {
        return deleteSiteCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref deleteSiteCommand, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete command is working fine and firing, so by explicitly giving  **canExecute** is not needed, though I have tried and not working I,e; view is not updating.

Comment: Did you try raising the **PropertyChanged** event with command?
Also check if the Binding mode is set to **TwoWay** for the  list itemssource

Comment: twoway is there for binding. PropertyChanged event also  tried implementing in setter of the property.

Comment: Please share more code. Hope you're using **ObservableCollection** and not **List** as the source. It is supposed to work if binding is set to two way and you're raising the propertychanged event.